Error trying to install the Mailjet.Api library
I want to install the Mailjet.Api library So that I can use his Api easily.
In the instructions on GitHub I see that I have to install using the following command:
PM> Install-Package Mailjet.Api
But when I run the above command in the visual studio terminal (where I want to use the library) I get an error:
'PM' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
And I don't understand. Maybe I didn't run the command in the right place.
And if so, where should I run the command?
I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!!

What you need is to open visual studio and then:
tools< NuGet Package Manager< Package Manager Console
and in the window that opens below run the command.
Successfully!
